# Solving equations with Standard Normal CDF and PDF (Optimization)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

How do we go about solving equations of this sort, where we need to find $x$ satisfying the below? Here $K$ and $\xi$ are known constants. Also, $\phi$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\xi\left(K-x\right)^{2}\phi\left(\xi\left\{ K-x\right\} \right)}{\Phi\left(\xi\left\{ K-x\right\} \right)}+\left(K-x\right)\left[\frac{\phi\left(\xi\left\{ K-x\right\} \right)}{\Phi\left(\xi\left\{ K-x\right\} \right)}\right]^{2} &  & =\\
\left\{ K-2x\right\} +\frac{1}{\xi}\frac{\phi\left(\xi\left\{ K-x\right\} \right)}{\Phi\left(\xi\left\{ K-x\right\} \right)}+\frac{\xi Kx\phi\left(\xi x\right)}{\Phi\left(\xi x\right)}+K\left[\frac{\phi\left(\xi x\right)}{\Phi\left(\xi x\right)}\right]^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

This comes up during the minimization of this problem.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{\left\{ x\right\} }{\min}\left[K\left\{ \xi x+\frac{\phi\left(\xi x\right)}{\Phi\left(\xi x\right)}\right\} +\left(K-x\right)\left\{ \xi\left(K-x\right)+\frac{\phi\left(\xi\left(K-x\right)\right)}{\Phi\left(\xi\left(K-x\right)\right)}\right\} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

Please note this can be shown to be convex and there is a separate thread on this.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158042/convexity-of-function-of-pdf-and-cdf-of-standard-normal-random-variable

Comment: Please clarify: are you seeking to solve the minimization problem, or do you need that nonlinear equation solved for _other_ reasons? Because it's not clear to me why you need to solve the equation at all.

Comment: (Because to be clear: you are not going to be solving the equation _or_ the minimization problem analytically. A numerical method is your only option, and most will not require that you solve this equation.)

Comment: @MichaelGrant ... Thanks for your comments. You are right, the end objective is to solve the minimization problem. So by using derivatives, First Order Conditions, we end up with the equation. And as you suggest, it seems that the only known ways are numerical methods. But I am stuck as to how to start. Can you please give me some pointers, specific to this problem? To approach both the minimization and the equation numerically.

Comment: The point is this: if you use numerical methods, use them on the _optimization problem_, not the _equation_. Use a descent method like gradient descent or Newton's method.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Thanks that might be a good suggestion. But why would they not be equivalent? (Because the numerical solution after the derivatives approach is an approximation on an approximation? or would there be other reasons?)

Comment: For some methods, they are equivalent. But strictly speaking, nonlinear equation solvers necessarily have to handle a _larger space_ of problems, because they have to work for equations that _aren't_ formed by the optimality conditions of optimization problems, too. Working with algorithms designed from the start from the problem _you care about most_ is likely to give you a richer set of choices and better performance. Yes, it's handwaving...

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Thanks for your pointers .. Much appreciated. I will see if anyone has any good suggestions on theoretical approximations for the same ... I will try to look for numerical solutions using R etc.